# Thread barrier for 49 threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am supposed to create 49 threads in a certain process( there are multiple processes here in my problem, so let's call the process P3). I have created those threads but the issue presents itself here: at any time, at most 5 threads are allowed to run in P3 without counting the main process. Thread 13 from P3 is allowed to end only if there are a total of 5 threads that are running(Thread 13 is among those 5 threads). My question is: how do I make sure that at some point of the program's execution there will be 5 threads running and among them there will be Thread 13 so it can end it's execution. I am using C as a programming language and Linux system calls. Moreover, I am not allowed to use "sleep()" and "usleep()".

This is a function in which I count the number of threads.

` void* thread_function2(void* arg)
{

```
TH_STRUCT* st=(TH_STRUCT*)arg;



sem_wait(&sem);

sem_wait(&sem2);
nrThreads++;
sem_post(&sem2);

printf("Number of threads running: %d\n",nrThreads);




sem_wait(&sem3);
nrThreads--;
sem_post(&sem3);

sem_post(&sem);

return 0;
```

} `

This part is from the main thread in which I create my threads: 
           `sem_init(&sem,0,5);
            sem_init(&sem2,0,1);
            sem_init(&sem3,0,1);
            sem_init(&sem4,0,1);`

```
        for(int i=1;i<=49;i++)
        {
            params1[i].procNum=3;
            params1[i].threadNum=i;
            pthread_create(&tids1[i],NULL,thread_function2,&params1[i]);
        }
```

`

Beginning a thread is done with the fuction info(args) which prints the word BEGIn and the thread number.
Ending a thread is done with a function info(args) which prints the word END and the thread number.
This is an example of an output and what the threads do when they begin and when they end:

```
[ ] BEGIN P5 T0 pid=30059 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ]  END  P5 T0 pid=30059 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ] BEGIN P6 T0 pid=30060 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ]  END  P6 T0 pid=30060 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ] BEGIN P7 T0 pid=30061 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ]  END  P7 T0 pid=30061 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ] BEGIN P8 T0 pid=30062 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ]  END  P8 T0 pid=30062 ppid=30009 tid=-99981504  
[ ]  END  P3 T0 pid=30009 ppid=30006 tid=-99981504  
[ ] BEGIN P9 T0 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-99981504  
[ ] BEGIN P9 T4 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-125163776  
[ ] BEGIN P9 T1 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-125163776  
[ ]  END  P9 T1 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-125163776  
[ ] BEGIN P9 T2 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-108378368  
[ ]  END  P9 T4 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-125163776  
[ ]  END  P9 T2 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-108378368  
[ ] BEGIN P9 T3 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-116771072  
[ ]  END  P9 T3 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-116771072  
[ ]  END  P9 T0 pid=30063 ppid=30006 tid=-99981504  
[ ]  END  P1 T0 pid=30006 ppid=3467 tid=-99981504
```

Comment: one would use semaphore to have some variable to track the number of thread (see : https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview)

Comment: This sounds like a really contrived homework assignment. Anyway, please post both your attempt, as well as more details on the assignment.

Comment: I posted the code for counting the threads.

Comment: Please do not post your code in a comment.  Rather post a [mcve] in the question so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @user3386109, You are right, "running at the same time" is ambiguous, but I think that in the context of this problem it means, "running _[concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing)_." The number of CPUs in a system does not limit the number of threads that can run concurrently: It only limits the number of threads that can run _[in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)_.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I posted more code and detail about the assignment.

Comment: when posting code in your question, each line needs to be indented 4 spaces beyond what your source code is indented.  Then it will all show up as code

Comment: Are there any other constraints? E.g., Would you be allowed to start four threads that all do nothing but wait for Thread_13 to die, then start Thread_13 which does nothing but die, then join all five of the threads run so far, and then finally, start and join 44 other do-nothing threads? That would seem to meet all of the requirements that you have stated, but it probably won't be what your professor was expecting.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I posted something at the end of my question regarding of what the threads do when they are started and ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,depends on if it matters when T13 will end.You can never know how long a thread will execute,so in the end there might not ever be 5 concurent threads running,If it doesnt matter when it will end you can count the number of threads and when the counter reaches 44, use a mutex on the last 5 threads.

```
int threads_running=0
pthread_t thread[49];
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int counter=0;
void *thread(some_args)
{
  if (threads_running==13) while (threads_running <5);

  if(counter==44)
  { 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    //do smth
    if(counter==49)
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 

  }
  else
 {
 //the rest of the threads do smth
  }
}
 int main()
{
  while (counter<49)
   {
     if(threads_running<5)
     { 
       pthread_create(&thread[counter],NULL,thread,thread_arg)
       counter+=1;
       threads_running+=1;
     }
    }

}
```

Comment: Re, "You can never know how long a thread will execute." You can put a lower bound on it by calling a `sleep(...)` function. You can also guarantee that the thread will not return before some important task is done by writing code for the thread that does not return until the important task is done.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the asker isn't allowed to use `sleep`.

Comment: I understood the mutex parts and now I am thinking of how am I going to make sure that from the time the counter reaches 44 the last 5 threads will contain Thread 13.Can I do that separately?Like with a pthread_join(thread[13],NULL)?

Comment: @tudors try to add it like so in the thread process


`
if (st.threadNum==13)
 while (threads_running <5);
`


this will lock the process until 5 threads are running concurently.
I cant format the code for the life of me,ill update the post.

Comment: @Kemikal I will try your solution here right away. Thank you for the help offered.

Comment: @Kemikal it freezes when it hits the fitfh thread of the process.  `if (st->procNum==3 && st->threadNum==13)  
 {  
  while(nrThreads<5)  
  {  
  
   if (tCounter==44)  
   {  
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
    info(BEGIN,st->procNum,st->threadNum);  

    info(END,st->procNum,st->threadNum);  
    if (tCounter==49)  
    {  
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);  
    }  
   }  
  }   
  
 } `   This is what I implemented.

Comment: @Kemikal and sometimes I get this :  missing thread(s) 13 in process 3
 missing END for thread 1 in process 3

Comment: try putting ";" after the while(nr threads) since thats  supposed to lock the 13 thread

Answer (score 0):

For such case a [semaphore](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) would be useful,

using :

- [`sem_init`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init) to initialize to the desired value
- [`sem_post`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post) to increment the value
- [`sem_wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait) to decrement and block 
  while the semaphore value is zero
- [`sem_getvalue`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_getvalue) to get the value of a semaphore 
  Example:

```
void *thread_proc(void* arg) {
   ...
   unbox arg in semaphore and id
   ...
   sem_wait(semaphore);
   // thread is running
   ...
   if(id == 13) { // special case for #13
       unsigned int count=1;
       while(count!=0) {
            sem_getvalue(semaphore,&count);
            pthread_yield();
       }
   }
   sem_post(semaphore);
   return YOUR_RESULT;
}
...
{
    sem_t semaphore;
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 5);

    for(int i=0;i<49;++i) {
        ...
        init a new thread and arg with i and semaphore to pass to the thread_proc
        ...

        pthread_create(thread, thread_proc, arg);
    }
```

Caveat there is not guarantee that 5 threads will run at the same time at anypoint in time.

One wait to cheat is to keep always 4 thread "running" and let one thread run and end at will until thread 13 would end the 4 blocked thread would be free to continue.

Comment: Yes, I am using semaphores but how do I make sure that at a certain point there will be 5 threads running and out of those there will be Thread13 so it can end.